# Update Statement?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have an SSIS Job that does a Weekly run every Monday. Currently the job pulls data from a spreadsheet, runs it through an aggregation (because I only need the annual SUM) and then puts the data into a Staging Table `[Staging.HRIS_RecruitingGL]`.

Both tables are structured identical.

```
TABLE [dbo].[HRIS_RecruitingGL](
      [FiscalYear] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
      [Amount] [decimal](20, 2) NOT NULL)
```

The data that is in the Staging Table looks like this.

```
|FiscalYear|Amount|
|2012      |250.25|
|2013      |175.13|
```

Since this report runs weekly I need the current year (and the following years) to be updated with the job. Therefor I need a script that will pull the data from the Staging Table and update the yearly amount on my Main table `[dbo.HRIS_RecruitingGL]`. This way the main table will grow as the years progress.

Since the Staging Table is truncated every time the Job runs I cant just load the data straight into the main table. Starting Monday the data I will receive will be for the current year (and future years) only, they removed the 2012 data.
But I need to keep it in my table so truncation of the Main table is not an option (that was my original method, truncate the table and load the new data, very simple)

Here is the Merge Statement that I tried to use.

```
MERGE dbo.HRIS_RecruitingGL AS tgt 
USING (
    SELECT  DATENAME(YEAR, GETDATE()) AS FiscleYear AND Amount,
    FROM Staging.HRIS_RecruitingGL
    ) AS rgl ON rgl.FiscalYear = tgt.FiscalYear
WHEN    MATCHED
    THEN    UPDATE
        SET tgt.FiscalYear = rgl.FiscalYear,
            tgt.Amount = rgl.Amount
WHEN    NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN    INSERT  (
                FiscalYear,
                Amount
            )
        VALUES  (
                rgl.FiscalYear,
                rgl,Amount
            );
```

What would be a script that i could use that would simply update the current years Amount from the Staging Table and also add a new row when the next year starts and update that information as well?

Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

UPDATE: 
I have changes the script as you suggested and I received the following Syntax error.

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'FiscleYear'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'FiscalYear'.
```

I have added a screen shot so that you can see the setup of the tables as well.
[image]

UPDATE:

I added the Script to an SQL Task in my SSIS package. When I ran the job it returned the following error message.

```
[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "MERGE   dbo.HRIS_RecruitingGL AS tgt    
USING   (..." failed with the following error: "The MERGE statement attempted to 
UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches 
more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the 
target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at 
most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.". Possible 
failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, 
parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
```

Comment: Can you post the structure of the `dbo.HRIS_RecruitingGL` table, including datatypes and constraints.

Comment: In your select from the staging table, you are not including the `Amount` field.

Comment: I added AND Amount at the end and it still gave me a "Syntax Error near the word FROM" error.

Comment: I am sure I am writing the select statement wrong. I have updated the OP to reflect the alteration I made.

Comment: In the SELECT, do you really mean to calculate the FiscalYear dynamically based on the current date OR do you want to retrieve it from the staging table? Remove the AND and replace it wit a comma and remove the comma after the amount field.

Comment: The staging table will be truncated and updated weekly, this will go on indefinitely. I need to keep the 2012 data so I moved it to the Main dbo table. Now going forward i want to have the main table updated with the data from the Staging Table based on the year. when 2014 rolls around I want it to add a row for 2014 with the amount from the staging table, but also continue to update the 2013 data in the event that accounting posts any updates for 2013 at the beginning of 2014. I hope that make sense.

Comment: In your `SELECT` change `FiscleYear` to `FiscalYear`. Sorry fro the typo in my answer,I have corrected it below.

Comment: I made the change and it returned a new Error message. 'Msg 110, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.'

Comment: I found the error, it was a comma where there should have been a period in the Values for [Amount]. Once I changed it the script ran successfully.

Comment: I updated the information in the OP. I added the script to a SQL task in my SSIS package. It returned an error that did not appear in the Query I tested in the SQL Manager.

Comment: Issue is corrected. I made a rookie mistake and forgot to truncate the Staging table.Thank you for all of your support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a `MERGE` instead of an `Update`. Merge will do an update where the keys match, and do an insert where the source key (from your staging table) is not found in the destination table.

See [this page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) for more info on Merge. Example "A" is the type of merge that you need.

Looking at your merge, you have not included the amount field from the staging table and you are calculating the fiscal year, which means you are not using the staging table at all.

I would expect the merge to look like the following, (all I have done is changed the `SELECT` clause on the staging table)

```
MERGE   dbo.HRIS_RecruitingGL AS tgt 
USING   (
        SELECT  FiscalYear,
                Amount
        FROM    Staging.HRIS_RecruitingGL
        )       AS rgl 
        ON      rgl.FiscalYear = tgt.FiscalYear
WHEN    MATCHED
THEN    UPDATE
        SET     tgt.FiscalYear = rgl.FiscalYear,
                tgt.Amount = rgl.Amount
WHEN    NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
THEN    INSERT  (
                FiscalYear,
                Amount
                )
        VALUES  (
                rgl.FiscalYear,
                rgl,Amount
                );
```

Comment: I thought this as well. I tried to use a Merge Statement from another project and just modify it but I could to get it to work.

Comment: Update your original post to include the merge statement and some details on the structure of the two tables. With that info you will get the answer you need.

Comment: I have updated the information. I'm a little new to this so i am sure I have probably made a rookie mistake somewhere in my script. Thank you for the guidance.